# Why do tensorflow and keras SimpleRNN layers have a default activation of tanh

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to use a relu activation for my simple RNN in a tensorflow model I am building.  It sits on top of a deep convolutional network.  I am trying to classify a sequence of images.  I noticed that the default activation in both keras and tensorflow source code is tanh for simple RNNs.  Is there a reason for this?  Is there anything wrong with using relu?  It seems like relu would help better with the vanishing gradients.

`nn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(1024, activation = tf.nn.relu)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RNNs can suffer from both exploding gradient and vanishing gradient problems. When the sequence to learn is long, then this can be a very delicate balance tipping into one or the other quite easily. Both problems are caused by exponentiation - each layer multiplies by weight matrix and derivative of activation, so if either the matrix magnitude or activation derivative is different from 1.0, there will be a tendency towards exploding or vanishing.

ReLUs do not help with exploding gradient problems. In fact they can be worse than activation functions which are naturally limited when weights are large such as sigmoid or tanh.

ReLUs *do* help with vanishing gradient problems. However, the designs of LSTM and GRU cells are also intended to address the same problem (of dealing with learning from potentially weak signals many time steps away), and do so very effectively.

For a simple RNN with short time series, there should be nothing wrong working with ReLU activation. To address the possibility of exploding gradients when training, you could look at gradient clipping (treating gradients outside of allowed range as being the min or max of that range).

Answer (score 2):

I can see two reasons:

1. LSTMs (the underlying RNN block) have been always defined in literature to use the `tanh` activation function. And that is what most users will expect from the implementation.
2. If I recall correctly `tanh` works better than `relu` for recurrent networks, but I can't find the paper / resource of this memory.

You are encouraged to experiment yourself on your particular dataset/problem which of the two activation functions perform best.

Comment: I understand why it works best for LSTMs but I am using SimpleRNNs since my sequence is only of length 6.